# Git clone with SSH shows error permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to clone a github repository but it gives me this error. (I'm using *cmder* bash on *Windows*)

What have I done wrong or am I missing something here? I can't understand why it's not working... Here is the error.

```
λ git clone git@github.com:squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer.git
Cloning into 'PHP_CodeSniffer'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also tried it like this and got this error:

```
λ git clone ssh://git@github.com:vuejs/vue.git
Cloning into 'vue'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:vuejs: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

1. **I generated an ssh key pair**

```
λ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\Martins/.ssh/id_rsa): C:\Users\Martins\.ssh\id_rsa_github
Your identification has been saved in C:\Users\Martins\.ssh\id_rsa_github.
Your public key has been saved in C:\Users\Martins\.ssh\id_rsa_github.pub.
The key fingerprint is: SHA256:Zdkc0cerbea3ofgBLavgOLzfLm5JiFw2hZXQ41C0CY martins@MartinsPC
```

2. **I added it to ssh-agent**

```
λ ssh-add C:\Users\Martins\.ssh\id_rsa_github
Identity added: C:\Users\Martins\.ssh\id_rsa_github (C:\Users\Martins\.ssh\id_rsa_github)
```

3. **I added it to my */.ssh/config* file**

```
Host github
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile C:\Users\Martins\.ssh\id_rsa_github
```

4. I added it to *Github* > *SSH and GPG keys* > *New SSH Key*

```
Title: Martins PC
Key: ssh-rsa AAAAB3HkbB1yc2EAAADAQBAAABAQxbprOpXw7qD9dnb1PIeo8AZ5YxaTUQ8wjpiBGcvw3WjcXCotBLgSWilahLdPVouGjlAh0xB0YB1g3oMrAqQRHb54CDzWJMUWqatzMwL+xorVqPKuNAGVxWcvgWBooteX7D/XrrW5kjUooBM9ffTO2gpP3WcKBMdtjQDZJB0Ba6W/zNMF+1k2u2kq6m7z9QBspMIMqYJhc4YsmOr96JUTFb2Gn4ekJ5kJqW3L5m0UBzwj6WS0DczcgEKUy5r3fZ7sBHS7vhc3ZnNtpfzSpBbL+j/Mgvz8CC+xDGkjR/J/29m7nL martins@MartinsPC
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. For anyone else who runs into this - the Host in my config file said "github" instead of "github.com". When I changed it to "github.com" now it is working.

It's still strange to me because I thought the Host section was for aliases only, maybe someone can explain that further.

Comment: That's true, but you must actually use the alias. The following could have possibly worked for "github" alias in ssh config:  git clone ssh://git@github:vuejs/vue.git